# Using Integer Declared Variable in JSP using c:set

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

```
                <c:set var="secCount" value="${0}">
                    <c:if test="${readaccess || empty param.id}">
                        <div class="row profile-data">
                            <div class="column large-3 medium-6 small-12 gry-txt">
                                <fmt:message key="profileView.secondarySkill" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="column large-9 medium-6 small-12">
                                <c:choose>
                                    <c:when test="${not empty employeeDTO.companyDetailsDTO.skillDTO}">
                                    <tr>
                                        <c:forEach items="${employeeDTO.companyDetailsDTO.skillDTO}" var="skill">
                                            <c:if test="${skill.skillTypeDTO.code=='SEC'}">
                                                <c:set var="secCount" value="${ secCount+1}"/>
                                                <td>${skill.skillNameDTO.name}</td>
                                            </c:if>
                                        </c:forEach>
                                        <c:if test="${ secCount==0}">
                                        <td>-</td>
                                        </c:if>
                                        </tr>
                                    </c:when>
                                    <c:otherwise>
                              -
                            </c:otherwise>
                                </c:choose>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </c:if>
                </c:set>
```

I want to ask that it is the right way to declare a integer and increment it just because I am getting this error

#### PWC6170: Validation error messages from TagLibraryValidator for c

867: Encountered illegal body of tag "c:set" tag, given its attributes.

908: Encountered illegal body of tag "c:set" tag, given its attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to the following code:

```
<c:set var="secCount" value="0" scope="page" />

...
<c:set var="secCount" value="${secCount + 1}" scope="page"/>
```

Comment: My reputation is low thats why not able to up like the comment .Thanks it worked.